# Shim a private method of a component with external dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I'm studying Microsoft Fakes to implement unit tests in a project of mine.

If i've understood correctly, i use stubs to set the behavior of external components (that implement interfaces) that the main component i want to test is dependent from.

I use shibs to simulate the behavior of specific pieces of code at runtime.

My goal is to test a method of a manager class that has dependencies to other components all implementing interfaces. This method, among the other things, calls a private method. 
In the test method i need to force the result of that private method.

The scenario is similar to the following code:

```
public class MyManager : IMyManager {

    private IMyDependentManager _myDependentManager;

    public MyManager(IMyDependentManager myDependentManager) {
        this._myDependentManager = myDependentManager;
    }

    public void MyMethodToTest(data1, data2,...) { // method to test
        ...
        byte[] res = MyPrivateMethod(data1); // i want to set the result of this method in order to NOT execute it, otherwise the test will fail
        ...
    }

    private byte[] MyPrivateMethod(data1) {

    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to setup the test would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication from the question and the private method's signature is that you need to separate the concerns.

Consider what the responsibility of your manager class is. Now consider what that private method is doing. I suspect you will find that the private method is not something that the manager class is (directly) responsible for - it is doing something that the manager should be delegating.

Move that private method into a separate class (as a public method), and use dependency injection to give it to the manager class, I would suggest doing this via an interface.

Now when testing your manager, you can supply it's constructor with a mock of the new class's interface to return whatever you like.

Comment: Is that a recommended way to proceed? I mean.. i created a private method because it is used only in that manager. Creating another manager implementing an interface defining only "MyPrivateMethod" means that i could use it in several other managers.

Comment: @Loris It doesn't matter how many things use the class, it's about separation of concerns. For example if I had a class responsible for saving and loading a record, and if that class was only used in one place I would still keep that class separate, I wouldn't just move those methods into the class which used it.

Comment: @Loris I wasn't sure if the final sentence on your comment was being said as a positive or a negative, so let me try to pick at bits of it... "Creating another manager" The new class doesn't have to be a 'manager'. "i could use it in several other managers" sounds like a good thing to me... and it means that you could provide multiple implementations of that interface. But if you're saying this as a negative, remember you can make both the new interface and the new class 'internal' if you don't want people outside your assembly 'seeing' it, it can be entirely encapsulated within your assembly.

Comment: I've got your point. It just seems strange to me that the solution to the problem essentially it's not to have private methods. I've seen that microsoft fakes (by using shims) allow you to redirect the result of private methods and i'm trying to figure out how can i use shims to do that if i have a situation similar to the one that i've pointed out in which i have dependencies to other managers.